# Scroll up in to browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui

I am using **Material UI** table in **React Application** . In one column, I have created Remove link . On the click of Remove link one dialog box get popup. In dialog box remove confirmation button appear . On the click of that confirm button the table row get deleted. I have done successfully for this . Problem is that when table row is deleted at the same time I am showing one message at the top of the page that particular team member is remove from table . Message is appear but the browser is not scroll up to show that message at the top.

Comment: Hey Dhruv, please add your code so that others can test the issue and fix it.

Comment: please add some executable code snippet, so that it would be helpful for someone to give answers correctly. See how to set [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: choose a diff way to show it's been deleted, like the [snackbar](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/) other than that use a trivial scroll to top `window.scrollTo(0,0)`, but it might be distracting

Comment: It is better to set css `position: fixed;` for message element so it always will be attached to the user's screen. Then you wouldn't need any scroll at all.

Comment: Thank you for kindly support team. I got the solution .In that Remove link with <a> tag replace with <div> and add the click event on <div>.